# "got the questions right (or wrong)."

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

I read a sentence.

> I want to know if I `got` that question `right`!

I am not sure if the word `right` is an adjective or an adverb.

And the meaning of `get` is also unclear to me.

I looked up dictionaries from which there are some similar examples.

`right/wrong` are **Adjectives**. And `get` means **cause**.

> Example A. Lots of people got the questions [wrong](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wrong).

> Example B. He got all his calculations [wrong](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/wrong_1).

These two examples A and B have a structure of *[VERB noun adjective]*

So I guess the the meaning of `get`  is **cause**.

Because example C has the same structure of *[VERB noun adjective]*

> Example C. I don't know if I can [get](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/get) it clean.

`right/wrong` are **Adverbs**. And `get` means **understand**.

> Example D. You've got it all [wrong](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/wrong_2).

`right/wrong` are **Adverbs**. And `get` means **make a mistake with**.

> Example F. I must have got the figures [wrong](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/wrong_2).

These question I have are a bit complicated. I try to use analogy to explain what I did not understand.

Sometimes it was helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a book on the various meanings of "get"  The OED definition is about 30000 words long, if you include all the examples.  These common verbs have many senses that are functional rather than meaningful.

Still it is clear that here "right" is an adjective, and describes the answers.  "Get" still means "receive" and the metaphor is that you have received the right answer for the question.